# How to create a java dynamic web project in vs-code

Tags: java, web, dynamic, project

I am following a Servlet and JSP tutorial video, where the instructor is creating a dynamic web project in Eclipse. My question is how to create a dynamic web project in VS-code. There is no such option when i click on new project in vs-code.
Please help ...

Comment: VS code is not an IDE, it's a code editor with plugins to help you write the code in different programming languages, there might be a plugin to do so for Java, I'm not sure, If you want to do it use IDE's such as Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans as instructor mentions.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

On welcome page click the java option highlighted, it will download all essential java support for vscode.
Then press '<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>' command palette will open.
Enter 'Java:Create Java Project' and select the desired type of project