# set-up Dynamic Web Project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

How to set up a Dynamic Web Project in VS Code?

How do i set up Dynamic Web Project in Vscode ? Its easy to do in eclipse since there is an option directly.. but there is no such option in Vscode.. I usually work on Eclipse but wanted to try it out using a different editor

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/66730554/1820778